# IIS 8.5 Intermittent 403.18 Errors On Server 2012 R2

Tags: .net, http, iis, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8.5

We are having an issue where IIS will return Intermittant 403.18 errors to client requests made from the same server. The server will run for days then a burst of these errors arrive. The IIS logs show the 403.18 being returned to the client. There is nothing in the windows Event logs.

We have turned on IIS extended logging for this error and the extended log for the error is shown below:

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>3</Level>
  <Opcode>16</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x100</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2021-04-23T16:26:50.365Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{80003D39-000E-FF00-B63F-84710C7967BB}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="16292" ThreadID="5764"/>
  <Computer>MY-SERVER</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{80003D39-000E-FF00-B63F-84710C7967BB}</Data>
  <Data Name="ModuleName">IIS Web Core</Data>
  <Data Name="Notification">1</Data>
  <Data Name="HttpStatus">403</Data>
  <Data Name="HttpReason">Forbidden</Data>
  <Data Name="HttpSubStatus">18</Data>
  <Data Name="ErrorCode">0</Data>
  <Data Name="ConfigExceptionInfo"></Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-GB">
  <Opcode>MODULE_SET_RESPONSE_ERROR_STATUS</Opcode>
  <Keywords>
   <Keyword>RequestNotifications</Keyword>
  </Keywords>
  <freb:Description Data="Notification">BEGIN_REQUEST</freb:Description>
  <freb:Description Data="ErrorCode">The operation completed successfully.
 (0x0)</freb:Description>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{002E91E3-E7AE-44AB-8E07-99230FFA6ADE}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
```

The full log can be found here [full iis extended log file](https://1drv.ms/t/s!Ar-z791J6YG3qD9HY0tvt9CDZXH1?e=bdCDAC)

The requests which cause the errors are serviced by an asp.net webservice. We see the errors returned by different URLs but they seem to happen in bursts and occur on ones which are quite frequent which led us to think it might be IIS's DynamicIpRestrictionModule. However this was turned off (and also tested by setting to very permissive values) and it did not help. We were also running mod-sec at one point which we thought might be the cause. However we removed mod-sec and it still happens. The intermittent nature is a puzzle because we see requests with exactly the same headers and body content which are serviced properly just minutes before and after the failed requests so it doesn't seem to be related to the request body or headers. The requests are made from the same server that is also servicing them.

As you can see the module producing the error is "IIS Web Core".

Comment: A custom error page is configured, and the custom error page resides in a different application pool than the application pool of the requested URL.

Comment: Thanks so much for this. There website application was indeed inheriting a web.config setting from a parent with a custom <httpErrors> section with an existingResponse attribute set to "Replace" and a landing page on a different application pool. If I correctly understand this would then "mask" the real error message. 

I have added  <httpErrors errorMode="Custom"><clear /><httpErrors> in my web.config for the offending website in the hope this removes the mask. I will update if it works. 

Thanks Muchy!